# query has no destination for result data - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have created the following stored procedure in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function incomingdel(IN del_ID varchar) RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE xyz integer;
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO xyz FROM incomingcheck(cast(del_ID as integer));
  IF xyz <> 1
  THEN
      SELECT * INTO xyz FROM perfdel(cast(del_ID as integer));
  END IF;

END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

even though the function returns VOID, I am still getting

```
Error: query has no destination for result data
```

when i execute the function. Can someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this function?

Answer (score 0):

When you do `SELECT * INTO ...` in a PL/pgSQL function you need to supply a variable of type `record` or of the row type of the row source, even if the function only returns an integer. The functions `incomingcheck(int)` and `perfdel(int)` are obviously returning a single `integer` in which case you can simplify your function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION incomingdel(del_ID integer) RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
  xyz integer;
BEGIN
  xyz := incomingcheck(del_ID);
  IF xyz <> 1 THEN
    xyz := perfdel(del_ID);
  END IF;
  -- Do something with xyz
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If the functionality is actually in the called functions (so you do not process the `xyz` value), then it becomes simpler still:

```
CREATE FUNCTION incomingdel(del_ID integer) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
  IF incomingcheck(del_ID) <> 1 THEN
    perfdel(del_ID);
  END IF;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```